# Cannot convert value of type 'NSAttributedString.DocumentAttributeKey' , "DocumentReadingOptionKey" also not working

Tags: swift, swift4, nsattributedstring

I upgraded from Swift 3 to Swift 4 and I get the `NSAttributedString` related error.

Here's my code:

```
viewModel.getInviteAFriendInfo(success: { message in
    if message.isEmpty{
        self.lblDetail.text = "xxxxxxx"
    }else{
        let htmlString: String = "<html><head><style xxxxxx </style></head><body>\(message)</body></html>"
        self.lblDetail.setText(try! NSAttributedString(data: htmlString.data(using: .unicode, allowLossyConversion: true)!, options: [NSAttributedString.DocumentAttributeKey.documentType:NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html,NSAttributedStringKey.kern: 2.0], documentAttributes: nil))
    }
}, failure: {
    self.showAlert("Failed to get text")
})
```

Here's my error:

> Cannot convert value of type 'NSAttributedString.DocumentAttributeKey' to expected dictionary key type 'NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey'

Read some posted questions and solutions, tried to change `NSAttributedString.DocumentAttributedKey` into `NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey`, but still got error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value you are trying to pass to the `options` parameter needs to be split up.

First, the `documentType` is from `NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey`, not `NSAttributedString.DocumentAttributeKey`.

Seconds, the `kern` needs to be passed to the `documentAttributes` parameter, not the `options` parameter.

It's much easier if you split up the code:

```
let options: [NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey : Any] = [ .documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html ]
let attributes = [ NSAttributedString.Key.kern: 2.0 ] as NSDictionary?
let data = htmlString.data(using: .utf8)!
let attrStr = try? NSAttributedString(data: data, options: options, documentAttributes: &attributes)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'm trying to find how to get htmlString.data from htmlString: String = "xxx" (sorry but I'm quite new in iOS)

Comment: See my updated answer. I forgot to go back earlier and finish that.

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind help! I passed the value "attrStr" as "self.lblDetail.setText(attrStr)" . The error gone! The original code is really too long and messy. It is great to split like this!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var htmlString: String = "<html><head><style xxxxxx </style></head><body>\(message)</body></html>"

if let attributedString = try? NSAttributedString(data: (htmlString.data(using: .unicode, allowLossyConversion: true)!), options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html], documentAttributes: nil) {
    self.lblDetail.attributedText = attributedString
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, it also fixed the error, but I'm not sure if it is ok that the "kern: 2.0" is not used.